# Does the iPad 3/4 charger use a standard C7/C8 interface?

Tags: ipad, charger

The new iPad chargers are sort of a brick containing the transformer, with a detachable corner piece containing the appropriate mains plug for wherever you bought it.

[image: An iPad 4 charger with corner detached lying on its side]

The corner piece looks like it connects to the brick with a standard unpolarized C7 socket / C8 plug:

[image: A standard C8 plug.]

I'm going from Europe to America and don't have an official bit to swap in on the charger, but I have a dozen C8 mains cables from other electronics. Can I just use one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happen to have a C8 plug from my PS Vita charger, and my iPad (3rd gen) charger here.  I plugged them into each other, and plugged in my iPhone.  Sure enough, it started charging my phone.

[image: picture showing c8 plugged in to ipad charger]

So yes, this does work fine.  C8 plugs will plug into the iPad 3 chargers.